# Expected Value of Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

What is the expected value of the absolute value of the difference between the number of incoming tails and the number of incoming heads  when a coin is tossed 5 times?

**Here is what I think :**  Let  $X$  is random variable of number of incoming heads then
$p=\frac{1}{2}$ and $n=5$ so $X\sim Binom(5,\frac{1}{2})$

$X$ and $Y=5-X$ ($Y$ is random variable of number of incoming tails) then $E(K)=E(\left|X-(5-X)\right|)=E(\left|2X-5\right|)=E(2X-5)=2E(X)-5=2.\frac{5}{2}-5=0$ where $K=\left|X-Y\right|=\left|2X-5\right|$ and $E(X)=n.p=5.\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{2}$

But the right answer is $\frac{15}{8}$. Where am I making a mistake? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's weird, I keep  getting $\frac{25}{3}$

Comment: Yes but the truth is $\frac{15}{8}$  :( @Alex

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: Nope , but stated in problem with paranthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your random variable $Z=|X-Y|$ can take only the values

$$\{1,3,5\}$$

with probabilities

$$\left\{\frac{20}{32};\frac{10}{32};\frac{2}{32}\right\}$$

This because

$Z=5$ when you get 5 consecutive tails (or heads)

$Z=3$ when you get 4 tails (or heads)

$Z=1$ when you get 2 tails (or heads)

No other situations are possible.

---

Thus its expectation is

$$\mathbb{E}[Z]=1\times \frac{20}{32}+3\times\frac{10}{32}+5\times\frac{2}{32}=\frac{15}{8}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $X\sim Binom(5,\frac{1}{2})$, the range of $X$ is $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, which implies that $2X - 5$ is not necessarily always positive. Therefore in your proof, it is not true that $E(\left|2X - 5\right|) = E(2X - 5)$.

Comment: I would assume that you prefer to work out the problem on your own, but feel free to let me know if you would like to have a corrected solution :)

Comment: Calculation the expected value from the scratch is done in 90 seconds ...